# Is std::unique_ptr the wrong tool to allocate memory for an array?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have an array of (for example) `uint8_t`s.

Is `std::unique_ptr` the wrong tool to use to manage this object in memory?

For example,

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t> data(new uint8_t[100]);
```

Will this produce undefined behaviour?

I want a smart-pointer object to manage some allocated memory for me. `std::vector` isn't ideal, because it is a dynamic object. `std::array` is no good either, because the size of allocation is not known at compile time. I cannot use the [currently, 2016-03-06] experimental `std::dynarray`, as this is not yet available on Visual Studio 2013.

Unfortunately I have to conform to VS2013, because, rules.

Comment: You do know that you can set the size of a vector, either using the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) or by manually [resizing it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) afterwards. So you can still use it as a "one time dynamic array".

Comment: "`std::vector` not ideal, because it is a dynamic object" -- why would that be a problem of a magnitude that makes you try manual memory management and / or experimental features instead?

Comment: Guys, having the ability to resize the memory, even clear it after allocation, would be a serious problem.

Comment: If you consider those things as problems, then simply don't do them? Nothing stops you from "clearing" or "resizing" (by resetting) the memory managed by a `std::unique_ptr` too. Using pointer (smart or not) also leads to other things, like having to keep track of the size yourself for example.

Comment: True, but would be risky to expose that functionality to the user.

Comment: I think it's time you tell us the use-case you are actually trying to solve by using smart pointers. If you haven't read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) before, now is a good time.

Answer (score 16):

The way you're using the `unique_ptr` will indeed result in undefined behavior because it'll `delete` the managed pointer, but you want it to be `delete[]`d instead. `unique_ptr` has a [partial specialization for array types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to handle such situations. What you need is

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> data(new uint8_t[100]);
```

You can also use [`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) for this

```
auto data = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(100);
```

There is a subtle difference between the two, however. Using `make_unique` will zero initialize the array, while the first method won't.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly `unique_ptr` as you've used it is incorrect because it will call `delete` rather than `delete[]` to deallocate the memory.

The normal solution to this situation is `std::vector`: It allocates and manages your memory as well as providing a fairly robust interface. You say that you don't want to use `vector` because `True, but would be risky to expose that functionality to the user.` from which I infer you're exposing the implementation detail of your container type to the interface of your class. *That* then is your real problem.

So use `vector` to manage the memory but don't expose `vector` directly in your class interface.